# How to pass wildcard string to git from bash / gnome terminal

Tags: bash, git, gnome-terminal

This command works in git 2.30.0.windows.1 through the Windows 'command' shell.

`git checkout [commit hash] -- */migrations/*`

It doesn't work with Mate terminal or bash (git 2.17). The problem is that they substitute the present content of the directories `*/migrations/*` (which are empty or don't have the files that were present at the commit I want to pull them from).  Mate terminal does this whether I single or double quote.

If I invoke Bash and then, at the new command line, add single or double quotes, git says that it doesn't have any files literally called `*/migrations/*`:

`error: pathspec '*/migrations/*' did not match any files known to git`

I can get the content of the migrations files if I substitute directories one at a time, but there are 20+ folders of migrations and I assume I have just missed a bit of lore about how to get what I want from a Linux terminal.  Can anyone suggest what I ought to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `*/migrations/*` syntax is referring to **nowhere** path. Neither **root** nor **current working directory**.
Try these with `ls` command before `checkout` with `git`:

- `*migrations/*`
- `./*migrations/*`
- `$PWD/migrations/*`

And if you got the right output with `ls` then apply it to `git checkout ...`

---

Test 1

```
ls */tmp/*
ls: cannot access '*/tmp/*': No such file or directory
```

Test 2

```
 ls /tmp/*
 it has output ...
 it has output ...
```

Comment: single quotes './*migrations/*' was the combination that finally did it!